# ansible lookup dig: list object has no attribute

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

Team,
am unable to understand or resolve this error. My task is pulling server name from a variable and performing dns lookup using dig module. any hint?  Exact same task works locally ubuntu desktop but when i run this via jenkins/container/ubuntu image it does not.

```
      - name: Validate DNS record lookup for {{ api_server_public_names }}
        debug: msg="{{ lookup('dig', '{{ api_server_public_names }}' )}}"
        vars:
          dns_response: "{{ lookup('dig', '{{ api_server_public_names }}' )}}"
        failed_when: not dns_response
```

```
 TASK [services-pre-install-checks : Validate DNS record lookup for [u'test.customer.com']] ***
  Thursday 31 October 2019  22:05:34 +0000 (0:00:00.037)       0:00:02.890 ****** 
  fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'dig'. Error was a <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>, original message: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'"}
15:05:34
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`api_server_public_names` is a list and cannot be used directly in the lookup. You will need to loop over the variable:

```
    - name: Validate DNS record lookup
      debug: msg="{{ lookup('dig', '{{ item }}' )}}"
      vars:
        dns_response: "{{ lookup('dig', '{{ item }}' )}}"
      failed_when: not dns_response
      loop: "{{ api_server_public_names }}"
```

Note however that your `failed_when` will not work as expected. You may need to do something similar to `failed_when: dns_response == "NXDOMAIN"`

Comment: that was it. thanks good catch. so how to make failed_when work? also, can't i use index instead of looping? like item[0] ? will it work as there is only one name in the  api_server_public_names

Comment: Yes `api_server_public_names[0]` or `api_server_public_names | first` will work without looping, though I question why it's a list if it only ever has 1 value. As for the `failed_when`, I gave an example but you may need to play around with it. If you are still struggling with it maybe create a new question.